# Can you refer to an object within its With block?

Tags: vba, excel

In a "With" block, is there a way to refer to the subject of the block itself?

For instance, if I wanted to copy text into a cell from the cell below it, I could say:

```
With MyRange    
    .cells(1).offset(1,0).copy .cells(1)
End With
```

But could I also do this?

```
With MyRange.cells(1)   
    .offset(1,0).copy [???]
End With
```

The "[???]" would be some simple way of saying "MyRange.Cells(1)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Offset(0) to refer to itself:

```
With MyRange.cells(1)   
    .Offset(1).Copy .Offset(0)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I like this one because it's easy to remember ".Offset(0)", and it applies to every type of range I can think of.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson there's only one type of `Range`. Other "types" of range are simply properties of various objects which return a `Range` object :)

Answer (score 4):

`.Cells` would work, as the `Cells` property will return the range itself.

```
With MyRange.cells(1)   
    .offset(1,0).copy .Cells
End With
```

The reasoning is this: `.Cells` property returns a range object, and you can use the `.Cells` against that range object, and further this extends to **any** property which returns a Range, such as:

```
With Sheet1.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    Debug.Print .Cells.Address  '#returns the address of entire "self" range in specified column's DataBodyRange
End With
```

The [`.DataBodyRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841252(v=office.14).aspx) property of a `ListObject` returns a `Range`.  So does the `ListColumns`, `HeaderRowRange`, etc.  Any property of any object which represents a range, returns a range. These other objects are not a class of their own, but a property of another object, which return a `Range`.

This accommodates single or multi-cell ranges. And of course, the `.Cells` can be fine-tuned if you need to manipulate *individual* cells, like: `.Cells(1)`, etc.

Comment: Does that mean that .Cells(1) is the same as .Cells(1).Cells(1) or .Cells(1).Cells(1).Cells(1).Cells(1).Cells(1)?

Comment: I appreciate your answer, David, and I'm certianly not going to downvote it, but I prefer Scott's answer. Because sometimes "MyRange.cells(1)" is instead something like "CurSheet.ListObjects(1).Listcolumns("Cash Balance").DataBodyRange". I'd have to think about what exactly to use in place of "Cells(1)"

Comment: @n8. Try for yourself :)

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson You'd still use `.Cells(1)`. **ANY** range object (such as the `DataBodyRange`) would follow the same protocols as a "normal" `Range` object.

Comment: Even if I wanted to paste a value into all cells in DataBodyRange? I'd still use .Cells(1)?

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson Actually even simpler, you could just do `.Cells` which returns the entire range.

Comment: Yup, it does!  Seems like you can just tack on `.Cells(1)` as many times as you want to no effect.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson  I would use the `.Cells` over `.Offset()`, mainly because it is less typing, but as David stated they do the same thing regardless the type of range object, so your choice.  I will not have my feelings hurt if the chosen correct answer is changed.

Comment: @n8 I'd guess there is probably *some* (I think the VBE only allows a certain length of characters per line), but practically speaking, you could probably build it in a recursive loop, almost infinitely until you run out of memory.